# Android SDK 23 RecyclerView and CardView missing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-6.0-marshmallow

I created a new app in Android Studio. The compileSdkVersion is 23.
Anyone knows why the RecyclerView and CardView are noware to be found? (Not through java code and not in layout xml files)

I'm surely not the only one who has encountered this problem.

Here is my build.gradle file for the app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Happened to me. Had to add everything manually like this: compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+' and the same for recyclerview

Comment: @Smashing thanks, is this a bug or something?

Comment: Really not sure. The funny thing is, on some projects it all just works and then sometimes it just decides not to get anything.

Comment: OK, thanks. Found it also at the bottom of this document: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Coolbeans man. Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem too and I managed to solve it doing the migration to 23.0.1 and also adding  either android:elevation and a bit of margin to the CardView.

Seems that previous to API 21 it does it programatically for simulating the shadows but in the new one you have to add it.

Comment: Yes, I wondered why the elevation was missing. I'll have to adjust that manually, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by changing build.gradle(Module:app) follow.
dependencies {

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

**compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'**

}

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the depedencies to the recyclerview and cardview support libraries. Add those two lines, sync the project and you will be able to find CardView and RecyclerView in both java code and xml.

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
```